# How to set up a C# program to work as a wrapper program to allow call and return functions to another C# program?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to write a data manager program (in C#) that reads and writes to an OPC UA server (a special type of tcp server), but takes "commands" from a C# windows form.

The idea basically being, the data manager controls read and write permissions and actions to the server and the windows form application will call to the data manager and request certain data from the server or request to write specific data to that server. The intent is that the data manager will be used btly various programs to  Thus, I want to write the data manager as a sort of "wrapper program" that can be called by the windows form application.

I have come across some possible solutions using publisher subscriber architectures, but I am unsure that type of architecture will be able to handle the amount of data we want to transfer at the rate we want to transfer it.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to accomplish this?

Comment: Sounds like you really want a library project. Not a console program.

Comment: it is possible to do that, but it needs some learning curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Message buss / queue

One option is as you say to use a message buss or queue, using some kind of sub/pub model. This require a "broker" that routes messages between clients. It is possible to run the broker in the same process as the data manager or UI, or to run it as a stand alone application. You will likely need some installation script that installs all the required applications. MQTT and RabbitMQ would be examples of such systems.

### Request response

You could also consider protocols that uses a request/response model instead of a sub/pub model. It may be more or less suitable than a message bus/queue depending on your specific use case. Http & gRPC would be examples of such protocols.

### Library

The by far simplest option is to just write your Data manager in a separate library, and run this from your UI application. This would also be the fastest option, and the one that is easiest to deploy. But it would mean that the data manager is only running when the UI is running.

A note about performance. It is hard to imagine how fast computers really are. Poor performance is often caused by doing repeated work, unnecessary work, or using poor algorithms. And performance is often hard to predict. You can make guesstimates based on bandwidth, frequency, experience etc. But the only reliable way to know if something will be fast enough is to test it. Preferably as early as possible to avoid wasting time on an unfeasible solution. I would recommend learning how to use tools like profilers, benchmarks, load testers, bandwidth limiters etc that make such testing easier and more reliable.